# Axes of an ellipsoid

Tags: notation, terminology, 3d, ellipsoids

A 3-Dimensional ellipsoid is given by the equation:

$$\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} + \frac{z^2}{c^2} = 1$$

Let $a=20, b=15$ and $c=10$. Then as per my understanding, $a$ is the major axes and $c$ is the minor axes. What axes is $b$ called? I am confused. Please provide some references too.

Comment: "Axis b" is good enough for me. "Median axis", if you want to sound fancy.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsoid) uses the term "median axis", so that apparently has some official sanction.